# split fullname into lastname firstname middlename and suffix

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I split fullname into Lastname Firstname Middlename suffix? 
eg: 
1.Smith John T PHD 
2.smith john 
3.smith john T 
name is separated by space .this name column has these 3 differnt types.

```
Desired output:
```

1) Smith  --  lastname 
    John   --  firstname
    T      --  middlename 
    Phd    --  Suffix

2)SMITH--LASTNAME
JOHN --FIRSTNAME

3) SMITH--LASTNAME
JOHN --FIRSTNAME
T--MIDDLENAME

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: Do _all_ names have this format?  Note that in general what you are trying to do is very difficult, especially in a database like SQL Server.

Comment: can you share some data for fullname

Comment: "Van Dyke" is a lastname. "Billy Bob" is a firstname. What do you propose for names components that contain spaces?  What you are asking for may be more difficult than you currently assume. Don't forget "Charles Jnr." or "Charles Snr." either.

Comment: I'd get an actual person to go through everything and update the new columns (because you should be storing this data separately) with the information. If the name in ambiguous, contact the person to find out. If you have millions of rows, that's going to take a long time, but otherwise you are definitely going to make wrong assumptions.

Comment: How would it look with the painter Pablo Picasso, how's full name is, in fact - `Pablo Diego José Francisco de Paula Juan Nepomuceno María de los Remedios Cipriano de la Santísima Trinidad Ruiz y Picasso`?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL 2016 or Azure SQL or Azure SQL Datawarehouse, you can use string_split function. [Read more on string_split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

```
DECLARE @tmp TABLE (Name NVARCHAR(100))

INSERT @tmp
SELECT 'Smith John T PHD'

SELECT CASE 
        WHEN rn = 1
            THEN 'LastName'
        WHEN rn = 2
            THEN 'FirstName'
        WHEN rn = 3
            THEN 'Middlename'
        WHEN rn = 4
            THEN 'Suffix'
        END AS NameType
    ,NAMES.value
FROM (
    SELECT row_number() OVER (
            ORDER BY (
                    SELECT 0
                    )
            ) AS rn
        ,s.value
    FROM @tmp AS t
    CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(t.Name, ' ') AS s
    ) AS NAMES
```

Answer (score 0):

```
         /*
            APPROACH:
            STEP 1: DECLARE FOUR VARIABLES TO HOLD -- LAST NAME, FIRST NAME, MIDDLE 
            NAME AND SUFFIX
            STEP 2: TRAVERSE THE STRING, AND KEEP A TRACK OF NUMBER OF SPACES YOU ARE 
            GETTING
             STEP 2.1 IF SPACE_NUM = 1, INITIALIZE THE STRINGS YOU ARE VISITED UPTO 
            NOW, INTO 'LAST NAME'
             STEP 2.2 IF SPACE_NUM = 2, INITIALIZE THE STRINGS YOU ARE VISITED UPTO 
            NOW, INTO 'FIRST NAME'
             STEP 2.3 IF SPACE_NUM = 3, INITIALIZE THE STRINGS YOU ARE VISITED UPTO 
            NOW, INTO 'MIDDLE NAME'
             STEP 3. INITIALIZE THE THE LAST STRINGS YOU VISITED INTO 'SUFFIX'

            NOTE: ASSUMING THE STRINGS ARE SAME FORMAT YOU MENTIONED.
            NOTE: FOR GETTING THE FIRST STRING A.K.A LAST NAME, WE HAVE TO PUT EXTRA- 
            SPACE IN FRONT OF STRING.
         */


         DECLARE @STRING AS VARCHAR(50) = 'Smith John T PHD'
         SET @STRING = ' '+@STRING

         DECLARE @FIRST_NAME AS VARCHAR(30) = ''
         DECLARE @LAST_NAME AS VARCHAR(30) = ''
         DECLARE @MIDDLE_NAME AS VARCHAR(30) = ''
         DECLARE @SUFFIX AS VARCHAR(30) = ''


         DECLARE @I AS INT = 1
         DECLARE @COUNT AS INT =0
         DECLARE @STR AS VARCHAR(20) =''

         WHILE @I <> LEN(@STRING)+1
         BEGIN
            IF SUBSTRING(@STRING, @I, 1) = ' '
            BEGIN
                SET @COUNT = @COUNT +1
                SET @I = @I +1
                CONTINUE
            END

            SET @STR += SUBSTRING(@STRING, @I, 1)

            IF @COUNT = 1
            BEGIN
                SET @LAST_NAME += @STR
                SET @STR = ''
            END

            IF @COUNT = 2
            BEGIN
                SET @FIRST_NAME += @STR
                SET @STR = ''
            END

            IF @COUNT = 3
            BEGIN
                SET @MIDDLE_NAME += @STR
                SET @STR = ''
            END
        SET @I = @I +1
        END

   SET @SUFFIX = @STR

    SELECT @FIRST_NAME AS "FIRST NAME", @LAST_NAME AS "LAST NAME", @MIDDLE_NAME 
     "Middle Name", @SUFFIX as "Suffix";
```

Answer (score 0):

If the fullname always in the specified format, then you can do :

```
select parsename(newcol, 4), parsename(newcol, 3), parsename(newcol, 2), parsename(newcol, 1)
from t cross apply
    ( values (replace(col, ' ', '.')) 
    ) tt(newcol);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
DECLARE @tmp TABLE (Name NVARCHAR(100))

INSERT @tmp
SELECT 'Smith John T PHD'

SELECT dtt.Name,dt2.SplitedName FROM
(
SELECT  ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS Id,
        Split.a.value('.','nvarchar(1000)') AS Name

FROM(
        SELECT CAST('<S>'+REPLACE(Name,' ','</S><S>')+'</S>' AS XML) Name
         FROM @tmp
    )dt 
CROSS APPLY Name.nodes('S') AS Split(a))dtt
INNER JOIN 
(   SELECT 1 AS id,  'lastname' AS SplitedName UNION ALL
        SELECT 2 ,  'firstname'  UNION ALL
        SELECT 3 ,  'middlename '  UNION ALL
        SELECT 4 ,  'Suffix' 
)dt2 ON dt2.ID=dtt.Id
```

Result

```
Name    SplitedName
-------------------
Smith   lastname
John    firstname
T       middlename 
PHD     Suffix
```